# Type of parameter accepted by strcpy() ?

Tags: c, string, strcpy

Why is that `strcpy()` accepting char array pointer even though the definition of `strcpy` is
 `char * strcpy( char * , const char * )` ??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char str[] = "Have A Nice Day";
    char ptr[17];

    strcpy(ptr, str);
    printf("%s", ptr);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134189/parameter-declaration-and-array

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is asking about `const` not about arrays vs pointers

Answer (score 4):

An array is not a pointer (although they are similar in behavior and usage), but it transparently decays to one in a context where a pointer is needed (like in the case where it's passed as a parameter to a function that expects a pointer).

A more in-depth description can be found in the [C FAQ 6.3](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html).

Answer (score -1):

An char[n] gives an address which can be used in place of a const pointer with memory allocated at time of declaration.

Comment: A `char[]` is not a const pointer, it is an incomplete array type. The two are not equivalent. Try compiling `extern char a[]; char f() { return a[0]; }` vs `extern char* const a; char f() { return a[0]; }` and looking at the difference.

Answer (score -4):

In C/C++ arrays are pointers as well.
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/9/ See here for more explanation.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. But an array identifier can be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first array element.

Comment: From the linked article:

"The difference between pointers and arrays

I have seen in many places that an array is introduced as a pointer. This is technically not correct. Arrays are not pointer. So what is it? It is like any other variable in C++."